# How do I edit the urls of the speed dial buttons in Opera Mobile?

Tags: opera-browser

How do I edit the urls of the speed dial buttons in Opera Mobile?

For example, I have a url  www.economist.com/printedition which redirects to a different url on different occasions. If I use the standard speed dial functionality, I will end up saving the redirected url instead of the printedition url.

Is there some file where these urls can be edited?

Answer (score 0):

Touch and hold the icon. A "Remove" and "Edit" should pop up. Drag and Drop the icon on the "Edit".  Now do your editing.